# Clarification in the differences between several time-series analysis models

Tags: time-series, arma

Can anybody give me a simple explanation of the differences among the following:

1. ARIMAX model
2. Regression with ARIMA errors
3. Transfer function model

Please provide some references if you can.

Comment: See http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/

Comment: @RobHyndman quick question, does this article mean that regression with ARIMA errors is equivalent to transfer function model or is it special case of transfer function model ?

Comment: A special case.

Comment: @RobHyndman Professor, what are the implications of autocorrelated exogenous input on ARMAX models? Can we use them as-is, if not what should be done during modeling?

Comment: Please do not use comments to ask new questions.